# Correct way to reference a variable in a different file/function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a variable `uid` and `user` in my App.js file where my user authentication happens via Google and Firebase. I'm trying to use the user.uid information and reference in my other file PlayerForm.jsx but obviously it is undefined there. What is the correct way to be able to access the data that is in that variable in App.js? I tried importing App.js to PlayerForm.jsx but an error was still thrown in regards to uid being used.

App.js (where uid is located)

```
var uid;

componentDidMount() {
  auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if (user) {
      this.setState({ user });
      uid = user.uid;
    }
  });
}
```

[Here's a gist](https://gist.github.com/scottmiller2/6e287529d5c00584ef407b42072427bf)

The first file is the one with authentication, and the variable is toward the bottom. The 2nd file is where I'd like to be able to access the information held in that variable.

Comment: is `PlayerForm` a child of `App` ? why not just use `props`?

Comment: If `PlayerForm` is a child of `App`, pass them as props.

Answer (score 0):

You can use global. in your app.js and use it everywhere.

```
global.user = {
    _id: "5lclkdclkc2e50d5412d594",
    name: "Jeff",
    etc.
}
```

In the other file, reference it by `global.user`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that App.js is the entry point of your app and PlayerForm.js is imported in App.js and called there. You can pass props to PlayerForm when calling it from App.js.

In App.js

```
import PlayerForm
...
<PlayerForm uid={user.uid} />
```

In PlayerForm.js

```
const PlayerForm({uid}) => (
   <div> `This is the ${uid}` </div>
)
export default PlayerForm
```

Comment: Is that valid JSX? I would have expected `<div>This is the {uid}</div>`

Comment: I have an `import PlayerForm from './PlayerForm/PlayerForm';` in App.js currently. Where would I put the `<PlayerForm uid={user.uid} />`?

Answer (score 0):

Export the user object from `App.js` in order to use inside the `PlayerForm.jsx`.

Example
**App.js**

```
export const user = {
  uid: '';
}
```

**PlayerForm.jsx**

```
import { users } from './App.js';
```